# Unable to connect non stop SQL from Spring boot applivcation

Tags: spring-boot, sqlmx

My project uses non stop SQL/MX as RDBMS database, a product from HP.I am not able to connect to the data source using Spring Boot's standard practice of defining JDBC URL, user, password inside application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.tandem.sqlmx.SQLMXDriver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlmx:
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SqlmxDialect
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM $USER1.TLFM3SQL.IF09CSTB
```

This is the error:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for 
connections. (com.tandem.sqlmx.SQLMXConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
    
JdbcEnvironmentInitiator: could not obtain connection to query metadata: Unable to resolve name 
[org.hibernate.dialect.SqlmxDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

Comment: Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: I figured out that for SQLMX, there is a hibernate jar which I didn't include. After adding the jar in pom, it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had not included SQLMX hibernate jar in project.
It worked after I included that jar in my pom.